# Pass date from Html to Ts in Angular on button click

Tags: angular, typescript, datetime, angular7, datetimepicker

I have a two dates in Html page which I want to pass to backend on button click, togheter with other parameters. This is what i have for now.

```
    <input [owlDateTime]="dt1" placeholder="From a date" [value]="dateFrom.value">
    <span [owlDateTimeTrigger]="dt1"><i class="fa fa-calendar"></i></span>
    <owl-date-time #dt1></owl-date-time>


    <input [owlDateTime]="dt2" placeholder="To a date" [value]="dateTo.value">
    <span [owlDateTimeTrigger]="dt2"><i class="fa fa-calendar"></i></span>
    <owl-date-time #dt2></owl-date-time>


    <button class="startButton" mat-raised-button color="primary"
       (click)="loadData(81,topSelect.value,txtFilter.value,dt1.getValidDate,dt2.getValidDate)">
      Search
      <i class="fa fa-search pb-icon" aria-hidden="true"></i>
    </button>
```

Here is Ts file:

```
  public loadData(customerId: number, topResult: number, searchTxt?: string, dateFrom?: Date, dateTo?: Date) {
    this.interfaceService.getLogsForCustomer(customerId, topResult, searchTxt, dateFrom, dateTo).subscribe((logs: Log[]) => {
      this.logs = logs;
      this.dataSource = new MatTableDataSource<Log>(this.logs);
      this.dataSource.paginator = this.paginator;
      this.dataSource.sort = this.sort;
      this.sort.sortChange.subscribe(() => this.paginator.pageIndex = 0);
    });
  }
```

Answer (score 3):

Add a form tag. You should either use

1. Template driven forms

or

2. Reactive forms.

When you use one of these you will get validation and a lot of help utils when user input is done.

If you dont want to use forms. You can use ngModel. The two way binding [(ngModel)] will update you values in the 'backend' without having to press the button